# jsPlumb with Angular 5+ Drag&Drop Connection

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, jsplumb, flowchart

I'm struggling with jsPlumb Community edition to connect elements with mouse by Drag& Drop.

I try to make a flow of elements connected by user and export to Json.

look:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsplumb-test-rx8hdy

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: https://jsplumb.github.io/jsplumb/draggable-connections-examples.html

Answer (score 7):

The main problem here is that you're creating a new instance of jsPlumb for each new node. The nodes can't be connected to each other if they are from different jsPlumb instances.

So the solution is to use one jsPlumb instance, for example, I've created one instance in NodeService:

```
@Injectable()
export class NodeService {

  jsPlumbInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance(); 
  ...

}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsplumb-test-2uyw3t?file=app/app.component.ts)**

[image]

In order to export your flowchart to json I would advise you setting `uuid` for each endpoint you add:

```
this.jsPlumbInstance.addEndpoint(id, { anchor: 'Bottom', uuid: id + '_bottom' }, Endpoint1);
                                                          /\
                                                        this one
```

This way you will be able to restore all the connections you've created in chart through the method:

```
jsPlumbInstance.connect({ uuids: connection.uuids });
```

All you need to do is to save json which contains two parts:

- nodes
- connections

**nodes-container.component.ts**

```
saveNodeJson(){
    //save element position on Canvas and node conections

    const container = this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.parentNode;
    const nodes = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('.node')).map((node: HTMLDivElement) => {
      return {
        id: node.id,
        top: node.offsetTop,
        left: node.offsetLeft, 
      }
    });

    const connections = (this.nodeService.jsPlumbInstance.getAllConnections() as any[])
        .map((conn) => ({ uuids: conn.getUuids() }));

    const json = JSON.stringify({ nodes, connections });

    console.log(json);
  }
```

Once you've saved the json you can restore the state:

**nodes-container.component.ts**

```
this.nodes.forEach(node => {
  this.nodeService.addDynamicNode(node);
});

setTimeout(() => { // we need it to make sure all nodes have been rendered
  this.connections.forEach(connection => {
    this.nodeService.addConnection(connection);
  });
})
```

where `addConnection` method is:

**node.service.ts**

```
addConnection(connection) {
  this.jsPlumbInstance.connect({ uuids: connection.uuids });
}
```

[**Stackblitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsplumb-test-axzamv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: on Stackblitz work like a charm, in my project in nodes-container.component.ts at @ViewChild('nodes', { read ; ViewContainerRef }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef 
=====>> Argument of type '{ read: typeof ViewContainerRef; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; static: boolean; }'.
  Property 'static' is missing in type '{ read: typeof ViewContainerRef; }' but required in type '{ read?: any; static: boolean; }'.

Comment: on Stackblitz is Angular 5 because i can't upgrade core-js DEPENDENCIES, in my project I have Angular: 8.1.1 and typescript: 3.4.3

Comment: Try additng`static` property, `@ViewChild('nodes', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;`

Comment: Souldn't static be `false` ?

Comment: Now I;m stuck in remove a node and zoom-in zoom-out :)) Any ideea ?? 
 @An-droid works with static:true.

Comment: For the zoom you can use another  module, for example https://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/vXYomB?editors=1010#0  or maybe some npm angular 2+ module

Comment: @yurzui Is it possible that the created node is not draggable? Like set up a list of nodes by default and give them position, only the line between their points would be draggable.

Comment: This is what I exactly needed !!